# Which website is best for freelancing?

Tags: freelance-websites, working-from-home, group-freelancing

I'm currently working as a freelancer at fiverr from the last few months. Now I've listen about many others sites for freelancers like freelancer,guru,upwork etc. I don't know which website is best for beginners. Anyone here, who wanted to share his/her experience with me. Every single suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There is only 1 best site - best site for you. That site can be the worst for me.

So the only solution is to try them ALL and find your best one.

Or simply use one with millions of freelancers and try to succeed there.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a single bullet to end your search for *best freelancing website*.

Also, instead of relying on a freelance website, your aim as a freelancer should be to build your own brand as the authority in your skill set / niche.

Apart from websites, social networking (both physical and on-line) is very useful for lead generation. Going to meetups, joining relevant LinkedIn and Facebook groups is very beneficial.

You may start the journey by applying at popular freelance websites, forums and groups related to your skill set but also keep building your portfolio on the side. Then come a day when you will get majority of your work from prospective clients landing on your website.

Hope this helps.